# How to access the route inside an ember initializer

Tags: ember.js

We're trying to create a check for a session inside the initializer and if there is none just route to our Sesssion route.

I can't seem to get a hold of and trigger `transitionToRoute` in any way, how do you do that?

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
    // Check if we now have an authToken, else transition to session
    if (container.lookup('service:session').get('authToken') === null) {
        var applicationRoute = container.lookup('route:index');
        // Below does not work
        //applicationRoute.transitionTo('session');
    }
}

export default {
  name: 'session-check',
  after: 'session-service',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Note: The "session-service" has the `after` option `store`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think you can transition during initialization. The application isn't fully set up and ready to route when initializers are running.

Comment: I found an example in "SimpleAuth" where this seems to be done: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin.js#L40-L53

I wonder if their "after" property with "simple-auth" is simply triggered later in the application. Must be an Ember-hook that's close to the same... Looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a `transitionTo` based on a returned value or variable, the place where you are supposed to do that are the route's hooks `beforeModel` and `afterModel`.

Comment: Would you recommend a mixin then, that hooks on beforeModel to check the session and make sure to use that in every Route?

Comment: Yes, that is a viable option, however it isn't the only solution. You should checkout the code for this project: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth

Comment: I already did! :) Found a satisfying solution that works, based on your suggestion. Created a sessionRouteMixin that has a beforeModel method which does this checking (and stores the attempted route). This mixin has a config of openRoutes which does not need a session, checking for this and the session in the beforeModel hook. Injected this mixin into my application route and now when attempting to reach a secure route (all secure by default) you are sent to the session route! Awesome!